# Can't convert symbol to integer from hash table

Tags: ruby

Edit:  The issue is being unable to get the quantity of arrays within the hash, so it can be, x = amount of arrays.  so it can be used as function.each_index{|x| code }

Trying to use the index of the amount of rows as a way of repeating an action X amount of times depending on how much data is pulled from a CSV file.

Terminal issued

```
=> Can't convert symbol to integer (TypeError)
```

Complete error:

```
=> ~/home/tests/Product.rb:30:in '[]' can't convert symbol into integer (TypeError) from ~home/tests/Product.rub:30:in 'getNumbRel'
from test.rb:36:in '<main>'
```

the function is that is performing the action is:

```
def getNumRel
  if defined? @releaseHashTable
     return @releaseHashTable[:releasename].length
  else
      @releaseHashTable = readReleaseCSV()
      return @releaseHashTable[:releasename].length
  end
end
```

The csv data pull is just a hash of arrays, nothing snazzy.

```
def readReleaseCSV()
   $log.info("Method "+"#{self.class.name}"+"."+"#{__method__}"+" has started")
   $log.debug("reading product csv file")
   # Create a Hash where the default is an empty Array
   result = Array.new
   csvPath = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}"+"/../../data/addingProdRelProjIterTestSuite/releaseCSVdata.csv"
   CSV.foreach(csvPath, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
     row.each do |column, value|
       if "#{column}" == "prodid"
         proHash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
         proHash['relid'] << row[:relid]
         proHash['releasename'] << row[:releasename]
         proHash['inheritcomponents'] << row[:inheritcomponents]

         productId = Integer(value)
         if result[productId] == nil
            result[productId] = Array.new
         end

         result[productId][result[productId].length] = proHash
      end
    end
  end
  $log.info("Method "+"#{self.class.name}"+"."+"#{__method__}"+" has finished")
  @productReleaseArr = result
 end
```

Comment: can you add the backtrace please

Comment: @kritchard mhm maybe a noob question, but what exactly is a backtrace?

Comment: Added, that now, hope it it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, couldn't resist, cleaned up your method.

```
# empty brackets unnecessary, no uppercase in method names
def read_release_csv
  # you don't need + here
  $log.info("Method #{self.class.name}.#{__method__} has started")
  $log.debug("reading product csv file")
  # you're returning this array. It is not a hash. [] is preferred over Array.new
  result = []
  csvPath = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../data/addingProdRelProjIterTestSuite/releaseCSVdata.csv"
  CSV.foreach(csvPath, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
    row.each do |column, value|
      # to_s is preferred
      if column.to_s == "prodid"
        proHash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] }
        proHash['relid'] << row[:relid]
        proHash['releasename'] << row[:releasename]
        proHash['inheritcomponents'] << row[:inheritcomponents]
        # to_i is preferred
        productId = value.to_i
        # this notation is preferred
        result[productId] ||= []
        # this is identical to what you did and more readable
        result[productId] << proHash
      end
    end
  end
  $log.info("Method #{self.class.name}.#{__method__} has finished")
  @productReleaseArr = result
end
```

Comment: Haha thank you, I haven't been scripting ruby for very long, I only know the basics.  Is this just a cleanup or is it a solution?

Comment: Heh, it was burning my eyes too. Given the rest of the code I'd want to go even further, as there seems to be too much slinging data structures around and converting from one to another. It needs to be OO-ified, with domain objects such as a `Product` class, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given much to go on, but it appears that `@releaseHashTable` contains an Array, not a Hash.

**Update**: Based on the implementation you posted, you can see that `productId` is an integer and that the return value of `readReleaseCSV()` is an array.

In order to get the `releasename` you want, you have to do this:

```
@releaseHashTable[productId][n][:releasename]
```

where `productId` and `n` are integers. Either you'll have to specify them specifically, or (if you don't know `n`) you'll have to introduce a loop to collect all the releasenames for all the products of a particular `productId`.

Comment: Hm maybe that is the issue, it's a little confusing for me as I didn't write the majority of scripts, I am just applying changes to some that were previously written.  Perhaps my understanding of how it is working is where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is what Mark Thomas meant:

```
> a = [1,2,3] # => [1, 2, 3] 
> a[:sym]
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
# here starts the backstrace
    from (irb):2:in `[]'
    from (irb):2
```

An Array is only accessible by an index like so `a[1]` this fetches the second element from the array
Your return a an array and thats why your code fails:

```
#....
result = Array.new
#....
@productReleaseArr = result
# and then later on you call
@releaseHashTable = readReleaseCSV()
@releaseHashTable[:releasename] # which gives you TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

Comment: Ah I see the misunderstanding, the function takes the row.length which should provide the number of arrays.  Which is what I need to use in the test.